# Anonymous comparator in constructor using a cast to Comparable

Tags: java, comparator, comparable, anonymous

I'm having trouble writing an anonymous comparator inside a constructor. My instructions are as follows:

" your code should assume that the key type is comparable, that is, implements Comparable"

However, we're using

```
private Comparator<K> _comparator;
```

Our Data strcture also has a private class of Node:

```
private static class Node<K,V> extends AbstractEntry<K,V> {
    Node<K,V> left, right;
    Node(K k, V v) {
        super(k,v);
        left = right = null;
    }
}
```

I did try writing it like this:

```
public TreeMap() {

    _comparator = (Comparator<K>) new Comparator<Node<K,V>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Node<K, V> o1, Node<K, V> o2) {
            return ((Integer) o1.getKey()).compareTo((Integer) o2.getKey());

        }
    };
}
```

But this isn't correct because we're not supposed to be comparing nodes, or assuming the that key is an Integer. I'm also supposed to use an unchecked cast to Comparable, and I can't figure out how or where to do this.

The actual instructions from the assignment are as follows:

There are two constructors in the class you will write: one takes a comparator for the key type, which must not be null. The other doesn't, but if this constructor is used, your code should assume that the key type is comparable, that is, implements Comparable. Then this assumption is used to create a comparator that uses the compareTo method to do its work.

Any hints or ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: *we're not supposed to be comparing nodes*: what are you supposed to compare? What is the comparator used for? What are the instructions?

Comment: Updated with more info that's hopefully helpful.

Answer (score 2):

OK. So you need to write a comparator that sorts comparable keys, using their natural ordering. I.e. it should just delegate to their compareTo method.

So you want

```
Comparator<K> comparator = (a, b) -> ((Comparable<K>) a).compareTo(b);
```

Or, if you really want to write it as an anonymous inner class:

```
Comparator<K> comparator = new Comparator<K>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(K a, K b) {
        return ((Comparable<K>) a).compareTo(b);
    }
};
```

Comment: Oh! I see. You're casting to Comparable inside compare and then calling the compareTo...I kept trying to cast Comparable somewhere in the declaration. Thank you so much! I've been stuck on this forever, lol.